# Ionic build android process exception error

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

,Hi to all, after running

```
cordova build --release android
```

i get this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I tried to find some fix in the internet but nothing works so i am open for any suggestions.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to get the full stack trace and post it here. Is there an option for getting cordova to print out the full stack trace when you build?

Comment: i can use cordova build --release android --stacktrace
but do not see any differences in console log 

Something that might be helpful is this erro:
Preparing output jar [C:\Users\Zoombayo\Desktop\Top-Photo\top-photo\platforms\android\build\intermediates\multi-dex\release\componentClasses.jar]
  Copying resources from program jar [C:\Users\Zoome\Desktop\myApp\myApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\release\jars\1\1f\combined.jar]
:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease FAILED

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my jdk up to 1.8.0 and everything run smoothly :)